# Как запросить права администратора на выполнение программы?

Tags: java

Например в C# можно изменить манифест и Windows запросит у пользователя разрешение. Есть какое-нибудь решение на JAVA? Нужно универсальное решение или костыль от Windows XP до Windows 10. Нужно это для того что-бы не возникло ошибки при установке программ на системный диск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator) есть описание ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)) - у Java программы тоже может быть файл манифеста, и в нем нужно использовать:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true|false"/>
```

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста Ваш ответ, приведите примеры.